# Functionally getting inserted row id for a reference

Tags: sql, database, f#, type-providers

I'm currently writing a database balancing module in F# with the usage of typeproviders to get some type safety.

I'm retrieving from a legacy database that is still currently active. When they add an entry (in this case an organisation) I need to balance to the new database. My problem is now that I need to both insert an organisation as well as a member that the organisation references.

**My question:** How to I retrieve the newly inserted id a nice matter? Below is my current progress.

```ml
let updatedOrgs = 
   newOrgs 
   |> Seq.map (fun (org, presi) -> 
      let q = "INSERT INTO members (title, firstname, lastname, phone_number, email, country) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
      let answer = localDb.DataContext.ExecuteQuery(q, presi.Title, presi.Firstname, presi.Lastname, presi.Phone_number, presi.Email, presi.Country)
      org.President_id <- (Seq.head answer)
      org)    

DB.Orgs.InsertAllOnSubmit(updatedOrgs)

DB.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
```

**Note:** In this code snippet I have executed directly on the database. I would prefer to do it in a type fashion, but I can't even start to comprehend how do that that.

Answer (score 0):

Ladies and gentlemen, the solution has found its way to me after reviewing the problem.

The problem turned out to be that while I was using the tables to reference each other, I had forgotten to add foreign keys from the organisation table to the member table.

By doing so one doesn't id to the member type and the database/type provider will resolve the automatic iterative id when inserting.